# Filebeat command not found

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

I am running ELK in a docker container at localhost, I am trying to [start filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-starting.html) (not through docker container) but I am receiving the error below.

> /etc/init.d/filebeat: command not found

Has anyone had similar issues or any idea how to resolve this?

Also they have mentioned:

> If you use an init.d script to start Filebeat on deb or rpm, you can’t specify command line flags (see Command Line Options). To specify flags, start Filebeat in the foreground.

But don't understood. I have checked a lot but nothing helped. I am running this in ubuntu 16.10

Comment: ubuntu or centos? your post says ubuntu, but your comment below says centos

Comment: These commands will done the job for you. 
`curl -L -O https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat/filebeat-7.3.2-amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i filebeat-7.3.2-amd64.deb`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to start filebeat on the host but you don't have it installed

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-installation.html

Comment: of course, I have installed it according to the instructions given in the page

Comment: What platform is this on?

Comment: this is running on centos 7 @7AC

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using a Linux distribution with systemd, have you tried starting filebeat as a systemd service? Check the status:

```
systemctl status -l filebeat
```

If that returns info about the service, then filebeat is set up to be a systemd service, not an init.d spawn. Enable it to have it persist after reboot with:

```
sudo systemctl enable filebeat
```

And start it with:

```
sudo systemctl start filebeat
```